# Azure Webjobs vs Azure Functions : How to choose

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I've created some [Azure Webjobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/) that use triggers and I've just learnt about [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/functions/).

From what I understand Azure Functions seem to overlap with Azure Webjobs features and I have some difficulty to understand when to choose between Function and Webjob:

- Unlike Webjobs, Functions can only be triggered, it hasn't been designed to run continuous process (but you can write code to create a continuous function).
- You can write Webjobs and Functions using many languages (C#, node.js, python ...) but you can write your function from the Azure portal so it is easier and quicker to develop test and deploy a Function.
- Webjobs run as background processes in the context of an App Service web app, API app, or mobile app whereas Functions run using a Classic/Dynamic App Service Plan.
- Regarding the scaling, Functions seems to give more possibilities since you can use a dynamic app service plan and you can scale a single function whereas for a webjob you have to scale the whole web app.

So for sure there is a pricing difference, if you have an existing web app running you can use it to run a webjob without any additional cost but if I don't have an existing web app and I have to write code to trigger a queue should I use a webjob or a Function ?

Is there any other considerations to keep in mind when you need to choose ?

Comment: This is a blog post I owe. :)

I'll try to prepare a response, but this may be a bit open ended for Stack Overflow, so you may need to ask this on MSDN if it gets closed.

Comment: Nice (short) blog post on this topic http://geekswithblogs.net/tmurphy/archive/2016/06/02/application-integration-azure-functions-vs-webjobs.aspx

Comment: @chris-anderson-msft Can we run PowerShell as webjob? Can we install PowerShell package on Webjob?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

There are a couple options here within App Service. I won't touch on Logic Apps or Azure Automation, which also touch this space.

### Azure WebJobs

[This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) is honestly the best explanation, but I'll summarize here.

#### On Demand WebJobs aka. Scheduled WebJobs aka. Triggered WebJobs

Triggered WebJobs are WebJobs which are run once when a URL is called or when the [schedule property is present in schedule.job](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON). Scheduled WebJobs are just WebJobs which have had an Azure Scheduler Job created to call our URL on a schedule, but we also support the schedule property, as mentioned previously.

Summary:

- `+` Executable/Script on demand
- `+` Scheduled executions
- `-` Have to trigger via .scm endpoint
- `-` Scaling is manual
- `-` VM is always required

#### Continuous WebJobs (non SDK)

These jobs run forever and we will wake them up when they crash. You need to enable Always On for these to work, which means running them in Basic tier and above.

Summary:

- `+` Executable/Script always running
- `-` Requires always on - Basic tier and above
- `-` VM is always required

#### Continuous WebJobs with the WebJobs SDK

These aren't anything from a "WebJobs the feature" point of view. Essentially, we have this sweet SDK we wrote targeting WebJobs which lets you execute code based on simple triggers. I'll talk about this more later on.

Summary:

- `+` Executable/Script always running
- `+` Richer logging/dashboard
- `+` Triggers supported along with long running tasks
- `-` Requires always on - Basic tier and above
- `-` Scaling is manual to set up
- `-` Getting started can be a bit tiresome
- `-` VM is always required

### Azure WebJobs SDK

Azure WebJobs SDK is a completely separate SDK from WebJobs the platform feature. It's designed to be run in a WebJob, but can really be run anywhere. We have customers who run them on worker roles and even on prem or other clouds, though support is only best effort.

The SDK is just about making it easy to run some code in reaction to some event and make binding to services/etc. easy. This is honestly best covered in some [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/), but the heart of it is that "event" + "code" nature. We've also done some cool extensiblity work, but that's secondary to the core purpose.

Summary:

- Most of these are mentioned above
- `+` You can extend and run whatever you want. Full control.
- `-` HTTP stuff is a little wonky, but it works

### Azure Functions

Azure Functions is all about taking that core purpose of the WebJobs SDK, hosting it as a service, and making it easy to get started with other languages. We also introduce the "Serverless" concept here because it made a lot of sense to do so - we know how our SDK scales, so we can do intelligent things for you.

Azure Functions is a very heavily managed experience. We aren't supporting bringing your own host. Currently, we don't support custom extensions but its something we're investigating. We're opinionated about what you can and can't do, but for the things we enable, they are slick, and easy to use and manage.

Most of the "framework" things we've done to improve Functions go through the WebJobs SDK, though. For instance, we'll be uploading a new NuGet for WebJobs which really drastically increases the speed of logging, which has huge perf benefits for WebJobs SDK users. In shipping Functions as "WebJobs SDK as a Service" we've really improved a lot of experience issues.

- `+` Lots of languages supported
- `+` Fully managed, dynamic scaling
- `+` Easy to use portal w/ UX for managing connections/etc.
- `-` Host not customizable (yet)
- `~` Runs in a separate "app" which requires some configuration in your repo, but makes long term maintenance much easier.
- `~` <strike>No tooling (yet)</strike> Some tooling is now in alpha or preview - https://www.npmjs.com/package/azurefunctions
  (update Feb 2017:
  Visual Studio Tools for Azure Functions now available in preview: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/)

I'm probably biased since Functions is our latest and greatest, but feel free to shoot more cons for Functions my way.

I'll probably end up publishing a blog which elaborates a bit more, but I tried to keep this as succinct as possible for this forum.

Comment: Chris I've implemented a sample project that use web jobs to prove the benefit of using microservices over monolithic app. Should it be relevant to use azure function to create a sample that show how to deal with microservices and serverless azure functions ? –

Comment: I could see that being useful. I know there is a lot of room to discuss how to transition from server to serverless application patterns. That kind of seems related to what you just described.

Comment: So Azure Function is running on top of the webjob sdk ? I've noticed (while changing some app settings) that my function app is running inside a web app, is that correct ? So functions inside the app are triggered by some kind of an internal webjob ?

Comment: Basically, we take your code and configuration and create a WebJob SDK Function (hence the name Azure Functions) under the covers. So your code is running inside a WebJob SDK Function that we're managing for you.

Comment: So all the functions in the same "Function App" run under the same webjob or there is a webjob per function ? I am just trying to figure out how to choose when to create a new app or just a new function. I saw that modifying an appsetting force the job to restart... Also I would like to know is I can use features from the Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions such as ErrorTrigger or SendGrid binding and how to use it ? May be I should ask a new question ^^

Comment: Every Function App has 1 host (Which you might think of as a WebJob). Your functions within a Function App share a file system, app settings, memory, cpu, etc. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT currently WebJobs can be run locally for testing/debugging, is there support for that with Functions? I've been having a fun time using storage triggers since they don't work with the storage emulator, I'd hate to have even less support for local dev if I switched to Functions.

Comment: Yup. We have an article on it coming soon. It's not had a lot of effort to make it "easy" yet though; something we will focus on going into GA. As with WebJobs SDK (because they share the same engine), totally offline development isn't a goal of ours today, but local development is a high priority for us.

Comment: Do Functions support timed scheduling, e.g. run every 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes. The timer trigger. Cron expression of {0 */30 * * * *}  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-triggers-bindings/#timer-trigger

Comment: Hi Chris. I have a console app on ironworker I'd like to port to azure functions. I was wondering the best way to go about this. It uses ninject, email, FTP and other external libraries to hook in to shopify. I was wondering what you'd suggest? currently a webhook loads the job payload in to ironMQ which retries 5 times if the worker fails. Is there some kind of Azure consultant you can chat to to get advice on porting solutions? If using an existing exe where do you then store your .config file settings? Thanks for your time

Comment: Might be best to ask this on another question or our MSDN forums (given that you have a number of questions). To run existing executables, you can call them from a function, like a PowerShell function. Forums - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: @Chris-Anderson MSFT - Hi Chris, wondering if you could help with this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/40862172/442396

Comment: using Azure functions means you are moving to serverless architecture and webjobs still will be a monolithic application depending on your web app services. Scalling is also automatic with azure functions but incase of  webjobs capacity is directly proportional to the web app tier you have chosen.

Comment: Is there a Project Template for Azure Functions on Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT, how do you scale to multiple region using azure function ?

Comment: Probably worth its own question, rather than it being a comment. In general, you just create a Function App in another region. Hard parts are the data you're using. Do you use the same databases/queues in each region? Maybe your database is read-only in your secondary regions and each region has its own queue. You can use Traffic Manager in front of your Function Apps to help manage any http traffic between regions.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT, how can I create a function that runs continuously? I basically need to listen to a web socket feed. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot. You should use a Continuous WebJob (just a console app in your language of choice, not using the WebJobs SDK)

Comment: @chris-anderson-msft Can we run PowerShell as webjob? Can we install PowerShell package on Webjob?

Comment: You can start any process for a plain WebJob. PowerShell is installed on the windows machines out of the box. You can import modules, but since you're not an admin certain tools like chocolately do not work, I believe.

I would recommend looking at Azure Functions PowerShell support the recently GA'd, though.

Comment: Very disappointed in autoscaling on Az Func. 200 x 2 seconds jobs take ... 143 - 240 seconds because instances spin up so slowly and at most 4-5 of them. And you get little control on behavior. Not suitable for my purpose.

Comment: I've found that creating integration tests is currently significantly more complicated with Azure Functions than WebJobs

Comment: I think Azure functions are not suitable for a long-running process as Function execution timeout is 5-10 for consumption plan while max 1hr for premium(Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-AWS unfortunately the links are down on your post.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson I'm not sure if an Azure Function or WebJob is correct for my particular need. I have an ARM template that deploys an Azure App Service, scaled to multiple instances.  Before any of those App Services start, I need an Entity Framework DB migration to initialize the database.  I *must* somehow instigate this from the ARM template.  So I'm picturing the ARM template simultaneously deploying an (aggregator) Azure Function (which the App Services depend on)...and having it do the migration.  Perhaps triggered by any/all of the App Service entrypoints, and it handles synchronization?

Answer (score 21):

Being Azure Functions based on the WebJobs SDK, they provide most of the functionality already available in WebJobs, but with some new cool capabilities.

In terms of **triggers**, in addition to those already available for WebJobs (e.g. Service Bus, Storage Queues, Storage Blobs, CRON schedules, WebHooks, EventHub, and File Cloud Storage providers), Azure Functions can be triggered as APIs. And HTTP calls don't require kudu credentials, but can be authenticated via Azure AD and third-party identity providers.

In regard to **outputs**, the only difference is that Functions can return a response when called via HTTP.

Both support a wide **variety of languages**, including: bash (.sh), batch (.bat / .cmd), C#, F#, Node.Js, PHP, PowerShell, and Python.

Being Functions currently in Preview, **tooling** is still not ideal. But Microsoft is working on it. Hopefully we get the same flexibility of developing and testing Functions locally as we currently do for WebJobs with Visual Studio.

The most significant and cool advantages brought by Functions is the alternative of having a **Dynamic Service Plan** with a **"Serverless" model**, in which we don't need to manage VM instances or scaling; it's all managed for us. Additionally, by not having dedicated instances, we only pay for the resources we actually use.

A more detailed comparison between the two here: 
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/09/14/azure-functions-or-webjobs/

HTH :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paco ! This comparison can interest a lot of persons :-) But I wasn't looking for a comparison but just trying to understand when I should go with functions rather than webjobs !

Comment: It's hard to have a clear cut guidance without knowing the context. That's why I believed having a comparison might be of help for people to choose :)
I would say that: 

`if (((preference == "Serverless") || (isRequired(flexibleHttpTriggers)) && (isOk(currentFunctionsTooling)))
{ goWithFunctions(); }
else 
{ continueWIthWebJobs(); }
`

:)

Comment: Functions can return a response when called via HTTP.But Functions are based on the WebJobs SDK. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: Probably it's better to say that they **were** based on the WebJobs SDK, but they have evolved quite a bit from there :)

Answer (score 19):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#functions-vs-webjobs) Azure Functions has the following that WebJobs doesn't:

- Automatic scaling (CPU and memory is scaled according to needs determined at runtime)
- Pay-per-use pricing (Consumption plan instead App Service plan)
- More trigger events (like WebHooks)
- In-browser development (Visual Studio still possible)
- F# support

Simply put: Azure Functions is the newer animal. If you don't already have an App Service plan I'd go with Functions because for the long-term I don't see any reasons  why starting with WebJobs would be better (Functions tooling might not be already as stable though).

Answer (score 19):

I would like to add two more point to the above long & little bit old posts. if you choose consumption plan in azure functions, below are the limitations

If you want to run any jobs more than 10 minutes choose webjobs. Azure functions, runs only for **5 minutes** by default,  if your process exceeds 5 minutes, then azure function throws timeout exception. You can **increase** the timeout to **10 minutes in host.json**.

Note: There is no timeout problem if you are using app service plan azure functions.

Another reason to distinguish is. if you use azure function, then your initial start time will be slow because the machines(containers) are created on the fly and destroyed once it is used.

To avoid cold start, azure function app have released premium plan, where one instance will be running all the time and based on the load the function app will start scaling and you will be billed for one instance and other instances based on consumption.

Comment: Your first point only apply is you are using the consumption plan, with a paid sku you don't have any timeout limit. I agree with the second point.

Comment: i think both points are valid for consumption plan. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: But you can choose appservice plan while creating azure functions. But it defeats the whole purpose though

Comment: @KarthikeyanVK, I am not sure if it is still accurate as the function runtime v2 allows more than 10 min ?

Comment: Looks like the timeout is still the same for v2 as in v1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Comment: The 10 minute limit is no longer a limitation with the introduction of Azure Durable Functions and Orchestration.

Answer (score 12):

I realize I'm very late to the game with this answer but since this is still a top search result on Google, I wanted to give some guidance on this topic strictly **from a cost perspective** since it seems that the OP has some concerns about cost.  There are already some great answers here that talk about the technical limitations and details of how each service works, so I am not going to rehash those answers.

If you absolutely need something that **runs for "free"** (as in no additional cost to what you've already paid for your web app) then you have two options:

1. Webjobs - deployed alongside your existing web app and uses the same resources as your web app.  There is no additional monetary cost to use webjobs but there are some limitations as already mentioned that can lead to performance costs on your web app.
2. Functions - When using the consumption plan, you are allotted a certain amount of free executions.  The number at the time of this writing is actually quite high, 1 million free executions.  However, the 1 million execution limit is not the limit that is likely to give you trouble; it's the 400K GB-s (gigabyte seconds).  This is basically a calculation of the amount of memory your function uses multiplied by the number of seconds it runs (see the official calculation on the [pricing page here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/)).  You will be surprised how quickly this free allotment gets used up.

If you are concerned about costs but **not limited to no costs** at all, then you have more options available.

1. Functions - You can run either in the consumption plan or the app service plan for a relatively inexpensive price.  Keep in mind though, the GB-s billing model.  If you are using the consumption plan and are doing frequent, "heavy" work - you might be surprised with a big bill.
2. Cloud Services - This options hasn't been discussed as an alternative, mainly because the OP didn't ask about it.  But this is also a viable option.  Cloud services are ultimately just VMs running in the cloud so you can run whatever background jobs you need on them and they scale up/down pretty well (although you have to wire up your own triggers for execution, a slight inconvenience compared to webjobs/functions). They have more initial cost associated with them (because you pay per instance whether you use it or not) but if you have jobs that need to run constantly and are doing a lot of "heavy" lifting, then cloud services might be a better choice because it is easier to manage/monitor a fixed priced VM than executions and gigabyte seconds, in my opinion.  The other nice thing about cloud services is that you never have to worry about timeouts or some of the other limitations mentioned in previous answers.

If you are interested in reading through some specific scenarios and why I would choose one (webjobs, functions, cloud services) over the other, I just recently wrote a blog post on [webjobs vs functions vs cloud services](http://www.zoeller.us/blog/2018/12/29/azure-functions-vs-web-jobs-vs-cloud-services).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dan :-) I would say Cloud service is still nice but I was thinking about comparing webjob and functions as they share the same core SDK and 2 yrs and a half before, I did not really understand the purpose of serverless :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to give what are the **commonalities** and **differences** between the two
Azure functions are built on top of AppService and WebJobs SDK. WebJobs SDK will give you more freedom to play with while Azure functions are more structured with fewer responsibilities for the developers.

When you look at the commonalities Both uses the function-oriented programming mode,
bindings for trigger/input/output, support external libraries and can run and debug locally Supportruntime toiletries.

Differences

```
|-----------------------|------------------|
|      Functions        |     Web Jobs     |
|-----------------------|------------------|
|Can support HTTP       | Can't support HTTP
|                       |  requests        |
|-----------------------|------------------|
|Supports a variety of  | Traditional .NET |
|languages/tools        | developer        |
|                       | experience       |
|-----------------------|------------------|
|Bindings are configured| Config files are |
|using attributes       | used             |
|-----------------------|------------------|
|Scale is managed by    | Scale is managed |
|Azure                  | by user          |
|-----------------------|------------------|
|Limited control over   |Host can be       |
|host                   |controlled by user|
--------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A major consideration is that Azure Functions quit supporting the full .NET Framework after version 1, which was discontinued with v2.0, and which will not be changing in the now in preview v3.0.

- Documentation makes this clear [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions),
- as does [this feedback response](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/34148206-azure-functions-v2-supporting-the-net-framewor),
- as well as [this github issue / response](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/790).

Meanwhile, this strong armed approach was thankfully not applied -- yet -- to [Azure WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started):

> Version 3.x of the WebJobs SDK supports both .NET Core and .NET Framework console apps.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Functions are the logical successor to WebJobs.

There are very few workloads that are more suited for WebJobs than for Azure Functions.  Applications that need to be running continuously or have high startup costs for example, and even those can be run on dedicated function configurations (by using [durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-long-running-serverless-workflow-with-durable-functions/)).

Microsoft itself states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs):

> Azure Functions offers more developer productivity than Azure App
> Service WebJobs does. It also offers more options for programming
> languages, development environments, Azure service integration, and
> pricing. For most scenarios, it's the best choice.
>
> Here are two scenarios for which WebJobs may be the best choice:
>
> - You need more control over the code that listens for events, the JobHost object. Functions offers a limited number of ways to customize
>   JobHost behavior in the host.json file. Sometimes you need to do
>   things that can't be specified by a string in a JSON file. For
>   example, only the WebJobs SDK lets you configure a custom retry policy
>   for Azure Storage.
> - You have an App Service app for which you want to run code snippets, and you want to manage them together in the same Azure
>   DevOps environment.
>
> For other scenarios where you want to run code snippets for
> integrating Azure or third-party services, choose Azure Functions over
> WebJobs with the WebJobs SDK.

Answer (score 1):

One answer I always found for this question was
You can Customize Host in Azure WebJobs but you cant Customize the host of Azure Functions,

An example for this is
"In a WebJob, you can create a custom retry policy for calls to external systems."

This kind of policy can't be configured in an Azure Function.

Comment: You can use polly to define resilience policy for http calls.