# Migrating Windows scheduled tasks or windows services to Azure Web Jobs

Tags: azure, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, azure-webjobs

We have couple of scheduled tasks associated with web application which we plan to move to Azure. Some are console apps and using Windows task scheduler to run them in time intervals.

Some are in form on windows services and we have pragmatically scheduled the tasks in threads. These tasks may connect to SQL database, cleanup storage or even send bulk emails to users.

What are the recommendations for moving those to Azure. Webjobs is the prime candidate so far we found. Basically our requirement is scheduling and monitoring. Any suggestions, samples or links to resources are welcome.

Comment: This is really broad, with no right answer (also, tool/tutorial recommendations are off-topic). The best place to start is with the documentation for each service (such as WebJobs and Functions), and then ask specific questions about them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidMakogon. I am working on some of the development with TimerTrigger, comes along with WebJob SDK extensions. Just wanting other developers to share their related experience.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to shchedule tasks is "Azure Function", it's based on the webjob SDK and it offers "Webjobs as a Service", no deployment is necessary.

Morover you can use a "dynamic service plan" with Azure Functions, with this service plan you pay only when the function is running.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610952/azure-webjobs-vs-azure-functions-how-to-choose) is a post which compare Azure Functions and Webjobs.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (and I already mentioned Functions in my comment).