# How can I make an ASP.NET WebAPI program running in an Azure instance update a database every minute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm very familiar with using WebAPI to respond to incoming HTTP requests but now I have a new requirement and I'm not really sure where to start.

What I would like to do is to have my application once deployed to the cloud, establish a connection to a database and update a column every minute.  The code needed to establish the connection and update the column is easy but my question is, where could I put this code?  Is there some part of a normal ASP.NET WebAPI such as one of the start files where I could code this and how/where could I put a function call?

Comment: Check out [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) for automated jobs, much easier to do. Or as you are in Azure, I think [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) might do it.

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping for some point in the application where I could call a function.  If possible would like to not add in other apps to do the job :-(

Comment: Hangfire is not another application, it's just added as a Nuget package and WebJobs are part of Azure. There is no other way to get a regular task running in a web project.

Comment: @DavidG he could use a Timer.  But I get the feeling this is an [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) anyhow.

Comment: @Will Well a timer would be vulnerable to app recycling etc. That's why there are tools like Hangfire to take this pain away. But I do agree it's likely x/y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try [Azure Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/scheduler/) which you can simply configure to call your Web API every minute.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for an [Azure Worker Role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803365.aspx) or an [Azure WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/). Depending on the scope of what you want to do. Azure Web Role for something a little more complicated.

Comment: AWR would be overkill for this, that's why I suggested WebJobs.

Comment: OP mentioned the scope, just updating a database every minute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Azure Function for a similar job - updating a DB every few minutes (in my case DocumentDB).
It has a timer trigger where you can provide your Cron expression for timer based operations.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-timer/

The only problem I have is version control on the code that is deployed to the Azure Function.

It's actually built on top of the Azure Webjobs SDK , you can read about the differences here - [Azure Webjobs vs Azure Functions : How to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610952/azure-webjobs-vs-azure-functions-how-to-choose)