# Using SendGrid in Azure worker role

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-worker-roles

Can someone tell me if SendGrid can be used in a Azure worker role project which does not use .net core? It would also be good to know what is better for using sendgrid for notifications. Worker role or web job or Azure functions?

While trying to use it in a project which is not .NET Core, I get the following error while creating the sendgrid client:

"'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in SendGrid.dll"

Thanks

-Ravi

Comment: When trying to use what? Try to provide a code snippet and some context, don't leave us hanging.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me if SendGrid can be used in a Azure worker role project which does not use .net core?

It should work in the Azure worker role. I also do a test , it works correctly on my side. The following is the demo code.

```
 private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
            var apiKey = "sendgrid APIkey";
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

            // TODO: Replace the following with your own logic.
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working");

                var msg = new SendGridMessage
                {
                    From = new EmailAddress("send email", "Sunguiguan"),
                    Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
                    PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                    HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
                };
                msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("another email", "test user"));
                client.SendEmailAsync(msg, cancellationToken).Wait(cancellationToken);

                await Task.Delay(1000*60, cancellationToken);
            }
    }
```

[image]

> It would also be good to know what is better for using sendgrid for notifications. Worker role or web job or Azure functions?

All of those services could use sendgrid for notification .It depends on what you wanted. We could reference [Azure Webjobs vs Azure Functions : How to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610952/azure-webjobs-vs-azure-functions-how-to-choose) and [Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) to get more info.