# Difference between Azure Function and Web Job Or Azure function Vs Web Job

Tags: azure-functions, webhooks, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

**Azure Function :**

- Azure function based on the web job SDK.
- Deployment through visual studio: not deploy as a package , its only create 
  function within resourceGroup"
- Consumption plan** and App service plan both available
- Don't support remote debugging.
- **return OUTPUT** when call via http.
- Integrate with webhook
- we can create Web Api.
- bydefault it support autoscale.

**Web Job :**

- web job sdk depends on language.(e.g. C#..)
- Always Deploy with App Service.(e.g. web App,web Api etc..)
- ** **Only** App service plan.
- Support Remote debugging.
- not return any value.
- not option to integrate with **webhook**.
- do not create web api.
- For Continious Trigger: its provide two options for Scale-

  - a. **multi instance** : scale your web jobs across all instances of app service plan
  - b. **single instance** - copy only single copy of your web job running regardless on app service plan instance count. "

Comment: Sorry what is your question? Are you trying to get a clear comparison of these two products? usecases ? Have you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610952/azure-webjobs-vs-azure-functions-how-to-choose ?

Comment: Azure Functions: Consumption plan and App service plan both available. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: is it possible to use webhook in Azure function. ?