# Can an Azure Web App consist exclusively of azure web jobs

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I am working on a solution that requires many continuously running web jobs. I don't want to package these with any of the Web Apps that are part of our product for reasons of isolation and performance.
I guess some Azure Dev Ops work is involved, but my question is do I have to create Web app with no code, like a Weather Forecast type of project in order to deploy my web jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Azure does not have any standalone resource for webjobs. You can create an empty webapp and use that to [host your webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#convertnolink). Or, you can check out Azure Function app which is quite similar to web jobs as it also utilizes WebJobs SDK but have some additional features as well as constrains. Chris has explained more in details in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36611919/4269420).